# Rails 7 How do I keep attachments in file_field when editing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I edit records that have attachments the file_field is still in the form, this time without any files selected and when I submit the form to update the record all of the previous attachments get removed How can I keep them?

Answer (score 0):

In a controller, you can restrict the attachment field,

```
def update
  @object.update(object_params)
end

def object_params
  params.permit(:name, :details,...) #remove attachment field from this list
end
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: can you please provide piece of code here, or sample code ?

Comment: I solved this problem by adding logic to my form wrapping the file_field ```<% if ! @object.images.attached? %> ... <% end %>```